# What does the max field mean in the output of db.<collectionname>.stats( )?

Tags: mongodb

I am looking at the output of `db.system.profile.stats()` and I'm curious about what the `max` field means in the returned document (running mongodb 2.2.2).

Here's an example:

```
> db.system.profile.stats()
{
    "ns" : "mydb.system.profile",
    "count" : 2476,
    "size" : 1012284,
    "avgObjSize" : 408.83844911147014,
    "storageSize" : 1052672,
    "numExtents" : 2,
    "nindexes" : 0,
    "lastExtentSize" : 4096,
    "paddingFactor" : 1,
    "systemFlags" : 0,
    "userFlags" : 0,
    "totalIndexSize" : 0,
    "indexSizes" : {

    },
    "capped" : true,
    "max" : 2147483647,
    "ok" : 1
}
```

There is no mention of `max` on the [official mongodb documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/collection-statistics/) of db.collection.stats().

Perhaps it has something to do with the fact that `system.profile` is a capped collection. Although max is definitely not the maximum size of the capped collection because (1) the `max` shown is a huge number and (2) my collection doesn't get larger than 2500 or so documents and the total size is much less than this.

Any thoughts?

Thanks,
Kevin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`max` is an optional setting for a capped collection to also limit the *number* of documents in the collection, instead of just limiting by number of bytes (`size`).

See docs [here](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/javascript/#db.createCollection).